# Flyway cannot find migrations inside Jar

Tags: java, flyway

I made a spring boot app and package as a JAR.

When I invoke my jar I have a parameter to force the application.properties, one is for dev , other is for prod.

On dev, I have the following configuration for flyway:

```
spring.flyway.check-location=false
spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:./src/main/resources/migrations
```

On Prod I have the following:

```
spring.flyway.check-location=false
spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:./BOOT-INF/classes/migrations
```

But on prod i cannot find the migrations.

Please note that I just change the location from src/main/java/resources, to boot-inf...because that how the jar is made of.

Any thoughts?

Before ask for errors, there is no messages, it just say there is nothing to migrate because it is looking on wrong path.

Comment: What is this `filesystem`? You should be using something like `classpath:/migrations` in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case (dev) it works, because the application is executed in the root project directory as default. It takes the development files, not the built files - which is not correct, because it brings no guarantee that it works in production  (the fact you actually see).

This doesn't work in production anymore, because `BOOT-INF` is inside the build package (JAR) and not a physical file you can reference with a filesystem path.

Files in `src/main/resources` are packed as a part of the JAR as well as `BOOT-INF/classes`. Files inside the JAR must be referenced via classpath. So, the settings should be in both cases:

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/migrations
```

Comment: @paulorodriguez If it helped, you can accept the answer.

Comment: sorry did not know

Comment: not working in my case